# Javascript remove event binding from Google Translate

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using google translate to translate my webpage:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>

new google.translate.TranslateElement({
    pageLanguage: 'en',     
    includedLanguages: 'en,tr,ro',  
    layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.HORIZONTAL,
    autoDisplay:false });
```

I'm also using hc-offcanvas/hc-offcanvas-nav.js for the menus.

The translation works fine but it throws out my click events. When I look at the debugger, the transaltor has added extra elements  and assigned it's own events to these.

[image: debugger view]

When I run the page it translates but then fails to navigate the menu. If I manually disable the events from within debugger the menu works as expected.

How can I prevent the Google translator assigning events or remove the events?
[image]

I have tried .off .unbind .undelegate but these do not remove the events.

Comment: the standard javascript way to remove event listeners is..... [removeEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener)

Comment: @2pha but this method needs the reference to the function object that was originally added as an event listener, and with those coming from Google, I doubt they have access to those here. (And the mentioned jQuery methods only work for events that have been added using jQuery methods to begin with, as far as I know.)

Comment: @CBroe that's correct, you would need a reference to the original listener function. I was not trying to answer, I was just pointing it out as the OP had mentioned all the other functions that he had tried to use to remove the event listener.